# Why the SparkSubmit process can't killed by "yarn application -kill appid"?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I submitted an spark streaming application to yarn cluster ( hadoop 2.5.0 ), then i executed "yarn application -kill appid" to end the application. I found that, all CoarseGrainedExecutorBackends exited but the SparkSubmit process still running.

Has anyone came across this problem ? How to kill the SparkSubmit gracefully ?